# How to stack getClass()

Tags: java

Why does the first line work but not the second:

```
Class<? extends Class> c1                  = (new Object()).getClass().getClass();
Class<? extends Class<? extends Class>> c2 = (new Object()).getClass().getClass().getClass();
```

Comment: My question is what are you actually trying to achieve here?  I'm having great difficulty trying to relate this to a real-world programming problem ... given that `(new Object()).getClass().getClass()` and `(new Object()).getClass().getClass().getClass()` are actually the same object.

Comment: @StephenC You are right. At this point I am trying to invoke getClass() in general method that can behave predictably no matter what class is passed as an argument. Understanding from your post that getClass() on an object that was already of type Class returns itself is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the API docs for [`Object.getClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29)

> **The actual result type is Class where |X| is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is called.**

So `(new Object()).getClass()` will return a `Class<? extends Object>`. We're going to call `getClass` on that. So the **X** will be `Class`, which will give us `Class<? extends Class>`.

Comment: I'm starting to understand. So if (new Object()).getClass() is Class<? extends Object> but the notion of "object" disappears through type erasure when you call getClass() on that result, calling (new Object()).getClass().getClass().getClass() can never be Class<? extends Class**<? extends Class>**> because the part in bold was erased. Got it

Comment: @Mishax Yup, `Class<? extends |Class<? extends Class>|>` is `Class<? extends Class>`. It's a bit confusing. Indeed 1.6 clarified the docs from 1.5 ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass() ). Really reflection wasn't suitable for generification, and this is one of the awkward points.

Answer (score 0):

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<capture#5-of ? extends Class> to 
Class<? extends Class<? extends Class>>
```

That's why. Looks like the raw typing breaks apart here. Generics get stripped of their type during compilation. It works again if you add the required type cast

```
Class<? extends Class<? extends Class>> c2 = 
(Class<? extends Class<? extends Class>>) (newObject()).getClass().getClass().getClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

Java uses **type erasure**. There is no such thing as

```
Class<? extends Class<? extends Class>>
```

In reality, there only is `Class<?>`. Everything else is virtual.

Now an object of a class with three generics `Example<G1, G2, G3>` will **at run time** only give you the guarantee to be of type `Example<?,?,?>` - remember, generics have been erased at runtime, and that is when `getClass()` is evaluated.

```
ArrayList<Integer> inta = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Double> doua = new ArrayList<Double>();
System.err.println(inta.getClass() == doua.getClass());
```

should return `true`. Therefore, the `getClass()` should also have the same type: `Class<ArrayList<?>>`. The outer type is known, and available at runtime. The generics have been erased.

To avoid programming errors, you can *cast* the type:

```
Class<ArrayList<Double>> dacls = (Class<ArrayList<Double>>) doua.getClass();
```

but then it will still be the same class as the integer arraylist.